# make 4 responsive column in a row with different size with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using bootstrap and I want to know how I can create a ROW with 4 column that the first column would be biger than 3 others,and the collection should be responsive,I want to know how i can do that?

Comment: RTFM: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: @pintxo you just beat me to it! Nasim that's what you're looking for - it allows dynamic columns to be set.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple code

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

```
 <div class="row>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
 </div>
```